# Can I book Uber without a SIM card?

Tags: airports, internet, uber

I want to use Uber to travel from the Rome, Zurich, and Amsterdam airports to my accommodations. I won't have a SIM, but want to book Uber cars; is that possible? Is there wifi at Rome, Amsterdam, and Zurich airports? And, once I've booked my Uber, but don't have wifi after leaving the airport, how do we find each other?

Answer (score 3):

The uber will say where you need to wait. Also, you will know the driver name and the car. After you ask, these info are enough. 
I already asked a Uber in the airport, and knowing where I need to wait, I have been there until my Uber arrives. It works very well. Remember that the driver will know your name and they will ask when they arrive.
So, you will need internet acesss only to ask, and could be a wifi connection.
I have been in Chicago during 10 days and I used this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am later, but just sharing.
Actually you can, if you have already an account and internet connection. I used to inform the driver about the exact location and some landmark (coffee shop etc) also inform I dont have a phone number to call (other than my roaming SIM card). Tried several time whenever I travel to India or Singapore.